# How to handle 404 exception for cross-origin request in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have the UI application rest service on a different host and when it's not available, I can't display the error correctly.

In a console I have a pretty ok message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myserver.net:30540/myservice. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

But in error handler I'm getting an object like this:

```
{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{...},"statusText":""}
```

So I can't get nor error message, nor status. How can I handle it properly?

Comment: need to add CORS  headers in server side

Comment: Perhaps you haven't catch the idea. My service is working ok, it has all the needed headers for cross-origin requests. The problem is in exception that happens when it's down.